# Missing CREATE DATABASE code in PowerDesigner script

Tags: sql-server, powerdesigner

I've created PDM in PowerDesigner and I want to generate a database of it. When I choose **Database -> Generate database** option in main menu, pop-up dialog is shown where I need to configure database properties like data source, credentials and other.

When I check another options in dialog window, everything seems OK to me, and **Create database** section is selected, meaning the *Create Database...* code will be included in script. When I generate script using **Direct generation** (General settings) option, result code doesn't consist *Create Database...* code.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Which DBMS (Oracle, MS SQL Server, SAP SQL Anywhere...) is your PDM targetting?

Comment: My PDM targets MSSQL database.

Comment: I did not understand the mention of "General settings"... What you see in the Preview tab, should be what will be written in the generated script, depending on the currrently selected Options.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not very good explanation... Especially script related to direct generation... But if you really mean script (as title of your question says) then most likely you need to create database in your model.

To get it open model properties and press New button near database row:

[image: PDM]

When model created you need to set corresponding checkbox in Options tab during generation of model (create database, drop, open and so on).